# Facebook-like sub folders: How To?

Tags: php, subdirectory

I am trying to create a page with profiles similar to facebook.  The question I have is: instead of having a site that says www.sitename.com/profile.php?username=Username as the URL, I want the page to say www.sitename.com/Username.

I know to show a URL like the latter one, you would have an index page in a folder named Username, but I don't know how to do it dynamically and to show it as a subfolder.

I am using php as my main language.

Answer (score 2):

[mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) for Apache has features to implement what you want. And I'm sure other mainstream web servers have similar capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve friendly urls using Apache's [mod rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html). Just enable it in Apache config and put the following to `.htaccess`, which will be in root of your application:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /(.*)$ /profile.php?username=$1
```

Also, [here's](http://www.9lessons.info/2009/11/pretty-urls-with-htaccess-file.html) a nice looking tutorial regarding friendly urls.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [htaccess](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Htaccess), [http.conf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Httpd.conf) or (if you are on IIS) [web.config](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web.config).

I use htaccess. Here's an example of how I allow for dynamic profiles:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^profile\/(.*)$ ./profile.php?profileId=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

`RewriteBase /` means that the `./profile.php?profileId=$1` path is from the root directory. And the RegExp `^profile\/(.*)$` will match something like `profile/1234` resulting in displaying `./profile.php?profileId=1234`

Hope that helps.

Comment: You need to use `/` not `./` otherwise Apache will try to load `profile/profile.php?...` as the file since 'profile' is currently acting as a directory.

Comment: The RewriteBase takes care of that. Since the htaccess is in `/` and therefore the `./` if from `/` and not `/profile/`

Comment: According to the documentation, RewriteBase only applies to relative paths (that don't have a `/` or `./` or `../` preceding them). A `./` specifically inquires that it should use the current directory to find the file, which is `/profile/`.

Comment: `./` is relative. And I use it all the time.

Comment: I've always assumed it was absolute because I was told a `./` is essentially replaced with the full path to the current directory, aka `./` => `/path/to/directory/`.

Comment: In this case it is a bit redundant. Since my rewrite base is `/` and I'm using `./profile.php` it will turn into `/./profile.php`. So I think it can just be `RewriteRule ^profile\/(.*)$ profile.php?profileId=$1 [L,NC,QSA]` instead.